# wget & curl output "No such file or directory"

Tags: file, curl, download, wget

```
wget https://some.url/with/a/file.txt
```

Returns `No such file or directory` despite `file.txt` being present at the location (can be downloaded via browser).
Also the directory to save to is writeable by the user running the command.

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. Your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [su]  , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are a lot of related threads but nothing helped.

Finally found out **there is an illegal character** in front of the url!

That was so hard to find I post it here in case anyone stumbles upon the same.

Comment: Care to elaborate? What was the illegal character?

Comment: Sorry I only remember it wasn't "visible" so I think it must have been U+FEFF or one of these: U+200B, U+200C, U+200D, U+200E,U+200F.

Comment: This happened to me copying the curl command from another application to the terminal. At the terminal prompt I had to delete the spaces and re-insert them for it to work. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Just ran into this trying to install lgpio...cut and paste from their website example (even though it looked like it was in a code box).  Delete the space between wget and the URL and replace...boom works fine.  Took me too long to find this solution, so thank you Steros 3 years later.

Answer (score 1):

Close the terminal and try again to run the script.

Comment: I don't know what was wrong in my session, but re-opening new session and executing same command (it was from history, so it's the same) worked.

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon this with a similar issue using curl.
The root cause for me was curl was unable to find the destination directory.

adding `--create-dirs` to the command will ask curl to create the directories if they do not exist, which solved my issue.

eg.

```
# I want to download this file to ~/development/csvs/saved_file.csv
# Assume I am executing from a ~/development/ directory, which has no csv dir

# this will not work
curl 'https://bla.com/cool_csv.csv' > csvs/saved_file.csv

# this will work
curl 'https://bla.com/cool_csv.csv' -o csvs/saved_file.csv --create-dirs
```

`-o` will replace `>` and will specify output

[reference question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40367413/how-do-i-download-a-file-to-a-newly-created-directory-with-curl-on-os-x)